# Creating a queue - removing the same value twice issue C++

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I have to create a queue class from a data file, it's basically a two column .dat file with a character in the first column and a corresponding number in the second column. In this program there are two queues, high priority and low priority.

The * asterisk and associated number denotes how many times to remove them from the queue, alternating between removing from the high queue and the low queue.

I can populate the queue without issue (high priority only goes to high etc) -- but when I remove characters from the queue it will remove characters from a queue it shouldn't have access to.

Snippet of main.cpp:

```
  //This is the main.cpp where characters are sent into the queue.

    if (number1 == 1 && character != '*')  //if number is 1, sends to high priority queue
    { 
        myHigh.addToQueue(character);  
    } 

    else if (number1 == 2 || number1 == 3 ||number1 == 4 || number1 == 5 && character != '*') 
    {
        myLow.addToQueue(character);
    }

    for (int i=1; i<=number1; i++) 
    {
        if (character == '*') 
        {      
            myHigh.takeAway();                
            myLow.takeAway();
            number1/=i;
            i=1;
        }         
    }
```

Snippet of the arrayQueue class:

```
//this is in the arrayQueue class, it should remove values from the queue
int arrayQueue::takeAway()
{
    char letter;

    if (empty())
        return -1;
    else 
    {
        letter = queueArray[remove];    
        remove = (remove+1)%maxSize;
        count--;
        size--;
        cout << letter << " has been serviced and removed from the queue" << endl;
        return letter;        
    }
}
```

Now, this works all fine if you just use myHigh.takeAway(); - the values get removed normally.  However, if you use myLow.takeAway(); -- even without the myHigh.takeAway() it removes values that should only be in the high priority queue.

Here is a portion of the output running ONLY the myLow.takeAway(), W is in the HIGH priority queue yet when running myLow.takeAway() it gets removed?

```
//OUTPUT
R has been added to the queue and is assigned number 1
T has been added to the queue and is assigned number 2
W has been added to the queue and is assigned number 1
A has been added to the queue and is assigned number 3
W has been serviced and removed from the queue
T has been serviced and removed from the queue
```

I hope I included enough to give anyone an idea of what's going on, any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment.  Are you allowed to use standard collections in your queue implementation?

Comment: It is for my data structures course -- we are supposed to create one from scratch.

Comment: my guess would be that the remove variable is wrong and you are accessing out of the bounds of your lower priority class.

Comment: The remove variable is set to remove=0; in the initializer.